# Why is my account suddenly merged with a totally different user's account?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, merge-accounts, sock-puppets

[My account](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/23944/jm97) has been merged with another user (previously named "moderator") on the suspicion that the latter was my sock puppet, but this is not the case.

Now, that user is using my account with their login ID, posting very bad questions (causing decrease in my reputation). They can now even see my login ID (this is breach of trust).

I want moderators to separate my account from that member as it was before. This situation is highly annoying. Two different users are using the same account and it is causing trouble.

Comment: how is it you log in? if you **Edit Profile & Settings** >> **My Logins** you should be able to remove any logins. otherwise change the passwords. in regards to rep drop from what i saw in non 101 rep accounts there's been no significant drop in rep from bad questions from what i can initally see. the only drops i have seen are from user removals

Comment: @Memor-X he posted a question on physics.se then I deleted it.

Comment: well like i said remove the logins that you know aren't yours (if you have any) and change your passwords.

Comment: @Memor-X but that would be injustice to other user

Comment: @Memor-X Just for reference, that's bad advice. When two users are merged by mistake, locking one out doesn't do much except make it harder to undo the merge later. The only thing to do is to *stop using the account* and contact us via the link at the bottom of any page ASAP.

Comment: @AdamLear my apologies. to me it just seemed odd that there was a second login where i assumed that the process of merging would just combine data under 1 login by altering user IDs associated to posts and the other login is either removed or locked out.

Comment: @Memor-X No, all login credentials are active - adding new ones is the most common use case for merging IIRC.

Answer (score 19):

Contact us through the "*Contact*" link at the bottom of the page and provide details.

[image]

An employee will review what happened and respond as soon as possible.

Comment: Isn't it better to suspend the account in those cases, to prevent the one who hacked it from abusing it? (And when things are cleared out and the real owner gains full control again, lift the suspension?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard This was not an automatic or self-initiated merge. No hacking involved.

Comment: I assume most of those cases are people on shared computers, so it's nearly impossible to verify their claims that it wasn't actually them. Any advise how they can prove their claims anyway? Bring signed document from the other people that they're the other user(s) perhaps?